# Using scanner input as constructor argument in java

Tags: java, encryption, input, constructor

I'm new to java and currently in an undergraduate programming course.  I've been given an assignment that requires me to create and encryption class then a tester class.  In the tester class I am to create two objects of the encryption class: one with the default constructor, then the other with parameterized constructor using two scanner inputs as arguments(password and key).  This is what I am having difficulty with.  I don't think I am doing this correctly.  Here is the code.  The error I am receiving when I compile it says "incompatible types, String cannot be converted to int".  I thank anyone who can help me.

```
public class Encryption
{
   private int key; 
   private String encryptedPassword;
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   public Encryption()
   {
      key = 0;
      encryptedPassword = "";
   }

   public Encryption(int key, String password)
   {
      this.key = key;
      password = password;   
      setPassword(password);
   }

   public void encrypt(String password)
   {
      char ch;
      for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++){
      ch = password.charAt(i);

      if (ch >= '!' && ch <= 'z'){
         ch = (char)(ch + key);

         if (ch  > 'z'){
            ch = (char)(ch - 'z' + '!' - 1);}

         else if (ch < '!'){
              ch = (char)(ch +'z' - '!' +1);}
              encryptedPassword = password + ch;             
         }
      }
   }

   public boolean isValidPassword (String password)
   {
      encrypt(password);
      if (password.equals(encryptedPassword))
      return true;
      else
      return false;
   }

   public String getEncryptedPassword()
   {
      return encryptedPassword;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password)
   {
      encrypt(password);
   }

   public int getKey()
   {
      return key;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return "The encrypted password is " + getEncryptedPassword() + ". " +  "The key used to generate this password is " + getKey() + ".";            
   }
}
```

Here is the tester class code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EncryptionTester
{   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a password.");
      String password = scan.next();

      while (password.length() < 8)
      {      
          System.out.println("The password must be at least 8 characters long. Your password is only " + password.length() + " characters long.");
          System.out.println("Enter a password.");
          password = scan.next();
      }

      System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10.");         
      int key = scan.nextInt();

      while (key < 1 || key > 10)
      {
         System.out.println("The key must be between 1 and 10. You entered " + key);
         System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
         key = scan.nextInt();
      }

      Encryption defaultEncryption = new Encryption();
      Encryption argEncryption = new Encryption(password, key);
    }
```

Comment: `public Encryption(int key, String password)` and `new Encryption(password, key);`, find the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the constructor as

```
new Encryption(password, key);
```

when the declaration is

```
public Encryption(int key, String password)
```

You need to pass in arguments in the same order they are specified in the parameter list. Try

```
new Encryption(key, password);
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple fix.  I'll probably encounter more bugaboos during this assignment.  Thank you

Comment: @Jengland Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer.